# will teak oil protect outdoor furniture from cracking?

Tags: outdoor, wooden-furniture

I have some old adirondack chairs that I got at yard sales. I oiled them all with teak oil last summer. Now I'm reading that I didn't need to save that teak oil just preserves color, not integrity.

I would love to keep the chairs from spitting and cracking and generally ensure longevity, but I'm not particularly attached to the color. Anyway, these are all old chairs at this point.

can I stop using teak oil on my lawn chairs?

What should I use?

Comment: The best is tung oil. But nothing stands forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My brother the shipbuilder (you'd think I would have just asked him first) recommended raw linseed, with a strong caveat about spontaneous combustibility.

Boiled linseed as an acceptable alternative.